# How to prove that new data fits old PCA

Tags: correlation, pca, procrustes-analysis

I have an old dataset, for which i perform PCA, show its significance (non-randomness). Now I have new data (obtained in a bit different conditions). And I want to say that independently from different conditions I may still have the same principal components. I perform PCA for joined dataset and obtain very similar (but not equal) loadings.

I have a **first idea** just to map new data on old PCs and prove, that PCs explain sufficient amount of variance. The main problem here - I do not understand how to calculate explained variance for mapped data. Usually I use just output from function.

**Second idea** to sample observations and plot histograms for loadings. Then I will show, that they are similar, but I have no ideas how to compare these histograms numerically.

**Do You have better ideas?**

Comment: This task could be approached in many ways. Your question is a bit broad. You have to formulate exactly what is "same principal components" and what is null hypothesis. Note, as a particular case, that PCA is a decomposition of covariance or correlation matrix, and so one of approaches may just to test the equality of such matrices between the datasets.

Comment: I know, that question is broad. The problem is I could not formulate null-hypothesis. The idea is to prove, that my components describe real life, but not my sample. I want to prove, that differences of PCs obtained for 1st group and for 2nd group are just noise. Their real values are equal for both groups.

Comment: Good advice concerning correlation matrices. But, obviously they will never be the same. Which test will allow me to say, that I could not reject hypothesis, that these matrices are the same?

Comment: I think your first idea is a good way to approach it. You project your new data onto your old PCs and measure the explained variance (it's just the sum of variances of projections, divided by the the sum of variance of all "new" variables). Then you project your new data onto the new PCs and measure the explained variance. The first will *have* to be smaller than the second but if they are pretty close then you can claim that PCs are reasonably stable.

Comment: @amoeba the problem is I don't understand what does it means- variance of my new data. I understand variance of scalars (so I have no problems to calculate variance of projections) but my observations are vectors, so I have a problem to calculate total variance.

Comment: Well, if you have points in 2D, then "total variance" simply means variance of x plus variance of y. Does it make sense?